# Does the climb speed you get from the Climbing Master feat override the climb speed you get from Gravity Boost?

Tags: movement, starfinder

The [Climbing Master](http://www.starjammersrd.com/feats/general-feats/climbing-master/) feat states:

> You gain a climb speed equal to your land speed.

Does this override the climb speed of 20 ft you get from Gravity Boost? For instance, can I run using the Climbing Master speed instead of the Gravity Boost speed?

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, you use the higher Climb Speed.

Each type of Speed, as any typed bonus, overlaps and does not stack. You use whichever source of Speed that you consider most advantageous (typically the higher one).